# Executing a program (.exe) from a USB stick

Tags: usb, executable

I have a USB stick mounted (it appears in the output of `lsblk`) and contains an executable file: `PortablePGP.exe` which has executable permission and a file: `autorun.inf`  I do not know how to launch this program from Ubuntu 14.04.

If I click on it I get:

> "STICK” contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?

And when I click  run  I get:

> Oops! There was a problem running this software. Unable to locate the program

Answer (score 3):

Files with the extension `.exe` are usually made for Windows, not for linux. In some cases such files can be run via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), but usually it is better to look for a linux program that can do the same or similar things.

In this particular case I think **`gpg`** is the linux alternative, and it comes (already installed) with Ubuntu. You can read `man gpg` and look for tutorials via the internet.